# perl one-liner to keep only desired lines

Tags: perl

I have a text file (input.txt) like this:

```
NP_414685.4: 15-26, 131-138, 441-465
NP_418580.2: 493-500
NP_418780.2: 36-48, 44-66
NP_418345.2:
NP_418473.3: 1-19, 567-1093
NP_418398.2:
```

I want a perl one-liner that keeps only those lines in file where ":" is followed by number range (that means, here, the lines containing "NP_418345.2:" and "NP_418398.2:" get deleted). For this I have tried:

```
perl  -ni -e "print unless /: \d/" -pi.bak input.txt del input.txt.bak
```

But it shows exactly same output as the input file.
What will be the exact pattern that I can match here?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `print unless` means `print if not` -- opposite to what you want.

More to the point, it doesn't make sense using both `-n` and `-p`, and when you do `-p` overrides the other.  While both of them open the input file(s) and set up the loop over lines, `-p` also prints `$_` for *every* iteration.  So with it you are reprinting every line.  See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Finally, you seem to be deleting the `.bak` file ... ?  Then don't make it. Use just `-i`

Altogether

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /:\s*\d+\s*-\s*\d+/' input.txt
```

If you do want to keep the backup file use `-i.bak` instead of `-i`

---

You can see the code equivalent to a one-liner with particular options with [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) (via [O](http://perldoc.perl.org/O.html) module)

Try: `perl -MO=Deparse -ne 1` and `perl -MO=Deparse -pe 1`

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if /:\s+\d+-\d/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
perl -ne 'print if /:\s*(\d+\s*-\s*\d+\s*,?\s*)+\s*$/' input.txt
```

Prints:

```
NP_414685.4: 15-26, 131-138, 441-465
NP_418580.2: 493-500
NP_418780.2: 36-48, 44-66
NP_418473.3: 1-19, 567-1093
```

I'm not sure if you want to match lines that are possibly like this:

```
NP_418580.2: 493-500, asdf
```

or this:

```
NP_418580.2: asdf
```

This answer will not print these lines, if given to it.

Comment: This works for the sample data. If there were non-digit characters it would not work as intended by the OP