# One-line program to delete files with few header lines

Tags: windows, perl

This is the next part of my earlier question [*perl one-liner to keep only desired lines*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256438/perl-one-liner-to-keep-only-desired-lines). Here I have many `*.fa` files in a folder.

Suppose for three files: `1.fa`, `2.fa`, `3.fa`

The contents of them are as follows:

#### 1.fa

```
>djhnk_9
abfgdddcfdafaf
ygdugidg
>kjvk.80
jdsfkdbfdkfadf
>jnck_q2
fdgsdfjghsjhsfddf
>7ytiu98
ihdlfwdfjdlfl]ol
```

#### 2.fa

```
>cj76
dkjfhkdjcfhdjk
>67q32
nscvsdkvklsflplsad
>kbvbk
cbjfdikjbfadkjfbka
```

#### 3.fa

```
>1290.5
mnzmnvjbsdjb
```

The lines that start with a `>` are the *headers* and the rest are the *feature* lines.

I want to delete those files that have 3 or fewer header lines. Here, file `2.fa` and file `3.fa` should be deleted.

As I am working on a Windows system, preferably I use a one-line Perl script like:

```
for %%F in ("*.fa") do  perl ...
```

Is there a one-line program for that?

Comment: I am surprised that you got away with your previous question, but you at least showed some effort in trying something yourself. In this case you have simply thrown out a requirement, asking that your work be done for you. That is unacceptable. Stack Overflow is a place where programmers may ask their peers about some code or a problem that has defied their own efforts for a significant time: it isn't a place to get your work done for free, although there are people here who are thirsty for experience points who will help you out anyway (see below).

Comment: *"As I am working on a Windows system, preferably I use a one-line Perl script like"* Please explain yourself. Why do you think that a one-line program is more suited to Windows? In general, "one-liners" are much more difficult to debug and to understand, and should be attempted only by seasoned Perl programmers. You need a very good excuse not to write a proper program if you expect to use the code more than once, or to pass it on to other people.

Comment: @Borodin I post much more comments than answer (I have a lot of example if you doubt that), even when my comment could be an acceptable answer, just because I feel like some people might suggest better answers... I would hardly call myself thirsty for reputation. As it happens I like writing one-liners, and the OP had made a decent effort on writing the question (even if he didn't show any code he had tried), so that's why I posted my answer.

Comment: @Dada: I accept that, but I'm not sure why you think a high ratio of comments to answers should be a good thing. Regarding "one-liners", I can understand how they may interest you, but I don't think they should ever be written for public consumption unless the situation specifically requires it. After all, code golf is also interesting, but a "golfed" solution is an inexpressive one and should be confined to recreation. Most importantly, a "one-liner" involves the command-line processor, and a command that works on Windows won't work on Linux. A proper program stands a much better chance.

Comment: @Dada: It looks superficially like this question requires a one-line solution, but I don't understand the OP's reasoning, and `perl -e "..."` has only disadvantages over `perl program.pl`. A lot of lessons can be learned from [**pl2bat**](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/win32/bin/pl2bat.pl) if it's essential that the Perl code be in the same file as the shell commands.

Comment: @Borodin I just meant that if I was thirsty for rep, I could post my comments as answers, and most of them would have positive score, but I don't (as a response to your ~"see bellow, he just wants rep" which wasn't true). As for one-liners, it's indeed not as robust and portable as code in files, but when the question is about getting an easy task done, I see nothing wrong with using a one-liner, it's faster to write, doesn't require creating a file (hmm, that may sound like a cheap argument)...

Comment: @Borodin And I feel like once you stop using oneliners, then well, you shouldn't use `-n` or `-i` as well because it's not as readable as a `for(@ARGV)` or creating the temporary file of `-i` on your own etc... I think understanding one-liners is only a problem for people who don't know perl, and who would anyway have a hard time understand the more verbose file version of the one-liner...

Comment: @Dada: I was most upset that you considered helping this OP, who wrote only a requirement and asked for a solution. They don't deserve your expertise. But in general I think you should post anything that looks like an answer as an answer. That way you will get proper peer scrutiny and appropriate privileges on the site.

Comment: @Dada: I completely agree: no command-line switches should be used. Ever. The one exception is the awkward `-i` which doesn't even work on Windows without a parameter. The alternative is the awkward `$^I = '.bak'`, and since it's unusual and scary to want to overwrite your input file, I generally pretend that the facility doesn't exist.

Comment: @Borodin I see what you mean, and even if we don't have the same opinion of one-liners, I think your point is valid. Usually, when someone is just asking for code I ask them what they've tried, but this time I felt like the question wasn't that bad, at least he took the time to write it in an understandable way... Thanks for your comments anyway, I like hearing argument I didn't thought about. (I'd like to continue this discussion a bit, should we move it to the chat?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126727/discussion-between-borodin-and-dada).

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please try to write some code by yourself to solve the problem, and only after come ask for help. You will learn more if you do that, and we won't feel like you're just asking us to write your code.
The problem is very simple though, so here's a solution.

**Note** that this solution should be considered as a quick fix. Borodin suggested cleaner, easier to understand and more portable way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40263070/4990392).

I would suggest doing this with perl like this :

```
perl -nE "$count{$ARGV}++ if /^>/; END { unlink grep { $count{$_} <= 3 } keys %count }" *.fa
```

(for the record, I'm using double-quotes`"` as the delimiter of the string since you are on windows, but if anyone wish to use this on an unix system, just change the double-quotes `"` for some single-quotes`'`).

**Explanations:**

- `-n` surround the code with `while(<>){...}`, which will read the files one by one.
- With `$count{$ARGV}++ if /^>/` we count the number of headers in each file : `$ARGV` holds the name of the file being read, and `/^>/` is true only if the line starts with `>`, ie. it's a header line.
- Finally ( the `END { .. }` part), we delete (with the function `unlink`) the files that have 3 headers or less : `keys %count` gives all the file names, and `grep { $count{$_} <= 3 }` retains only the files that have 3 or less header lines to delete them.

Comment: This uses the very nasty unbalanced braces that presume the structure of the code that `perl -ne` will generate. It's far from self-documenting and, while you may do what you like to yourself in a private place, please don't expose yourself to the more polite world at large. Also, `%h` is a hash: we know it's a hash because you index it with braces, so there's no need to call it `%h`. It contains counts, so perhaps `%c` or `%count` or `%n`?

Comment: @Borodin I guess you're right, I changed it to an `END` block, it will be more readable and robust. For the record (not an excuse), I learned to use `}{` because I saw it on one of your answers (long ago). I renamed the hash `count` has you suggested, thanks.

Comment: @Dada: Please give me a reference. I would be astonished if I indulged in such unpleasantries, but I guess we all have to grow up. It is the sort of thing that is pursued by people who like the awful [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret) module; unfortunately its presence on CPAN gives it a lot of authority that it doesn't deserve

Comment: @Borodin It was months or years ago, I have no idea what was the question you were answering, but I'm pretty sure it was one of your answers. But it doesn't matter, I agree that it's better to use an `END` block on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Dada: Thanks Let me know if you uncover it. I have cringed once or twice at some older answers of mine, so it's not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a program. "One-liners" are inscrutable, non-portable, and very hard to debug

This does as you ask. I hope it's clear that I have commented out the `unlink` call for testing purposes: it would be a pain to regenerate the `*.fa` files each time

You will probably want to change `'[0-9].fa'` to just `*.fa`. I had other files in my own directory that I didn't want to be considered

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( my $file = glob '[0-9].fa' ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    my $headers = grep /^>/, <$fh>;

    #unlink $file if $headers <= 3;
    print qq{deleting "$file"\n} if $headers <= 3;
}
```

#### output

```
deleting "2.fa"
deleting "3.fa"
```